# Why run spark-submit but resources are not as required and spark no working?

Tags: apache-spark

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode client --master yarn --driver-memory 3g --executor-memory 3g --num-executors 2 --executor-cores 2 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false /app/main.py
```

### This is file spark-env.sh:

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/app/hadoop-3.3.6  export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop export  YARN_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop export  SPARK_MASTER_HOST=192.168.71.190 export JAVA_HOME=/app/jdk-11.0.20/ export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/app/anaconda3/bin/python3.11 export  PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/app/anaconda3/bin/python3.11  MASTER="yarn-cluster"  MASTER="yarn" SPARK_EXECUTOR_INSTANCES="2"
```

### This is file spark-default.conf:

`spark.blockManager.port 30000  spark.broadcast.port 30001  spark.driver.port 30002  spark.executor.port 30003  spark.fileserver.port 30004  spark.replClassServer.port 30005  spark.shuffle.service.port 30006  spark.master    yarn  spark.driver.memory 4g  spark.yarn.am.memory 4g  spark.executor.memory 4g`

### This is file yarn-site:

```
`<property>`  
`<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>`  
`<value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>`  
`</property>`  
`<property>`  
`<name>yarn.nodemanager.auxservices.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>          <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>`  
`</property>`  
`<property>`  
`<name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>`  
`<value>192.168.71.190</value>`  
`</property>`  
`<property>`  
`<name>yarn.acl.enable</name>`  
`<value>0</value> </property>`
`<property>`  
`<name>yarn.nodemanager.env-whitelist</name>   <value>JAVA_HOME,HADOOP_COMMON_HOME,HADOOP_HDFS_HOME,HADOOP_CONF_DIR,CLASSPATH_PERPEND_DISTCACHE,HADOOP_YARN_HOME,HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME</value>`
`</property>`
`<property>`  
`<name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>`  
`<value>8</value> </property> <property>`  
`<name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>`

`<value>16384</value> </property> <property>`  
`<name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>`  
`<value>16384</value> </property> <property>`  
`<name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>`  
`<value>512</value> </property> <property>`  
`<name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>`  
`<value>true</value> </property>`
```

### This is image when I went checking UI yarn

[image]